# Как выбрать строки согласно множественному условию в sql

Tags: sql

Есть такого рода таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо оставить только те строки, в которых поле Man_reg принимает все значения от 1 до 3. Другими словами должны остаться только строчки, где Man_reg 'Moscow' в данном примере. Но нужен код, по которому можно выбирать все такие строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... или

```sql
SELECT Man_reg
FROM tbl
WHERE Man_type IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY Man_reg
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Man_type) = 3;
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Возможный вариант для MySQL:

```
SELECT Man_reg 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Man_reg
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Man_type ORDER BY Man_type ASC) = '1,2,3';
```

[Проверить MySQL-запрос онлайн](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=50cbed66f743184c4fa17955ab962eb0&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Answer (score 2):

Если лист значений заранее не известен, то поможет такой запрос:

```
select a.man_reg
from tbl a
join (
    select distinct man_type, count (distinct man_type) over () total  
    from tbl) b on b.man_type = a.man_type
group by a.man_reg, total having count (*) = total
```